# Failed to access IIS metabase

Tags: asp.net, iis-5

Hi all i am getting the following error i tried all the available answers but still i am getting the same error can any one  tell what's wrong in my `local host`. I am using `IIS5.1`. Can any one help me please

`Failed to access IIS metabase.`

I am having the following framework `v2.0.50727`

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to do? Maybe some code?

Comment: I am just trying to browse a website from local host . There is no code. I just create a default page with some text on that

Comment: Please take a look here: http://forums.iis.net/p/1148195/1864453.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

`c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -ga ASPNET`